# Read value from adress with pointers - C programming

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic

In my program, I want to input some numbers until I input 0. When I input 0, the program must stop and show the numbers in order. It's almost finish but I have one problem. I must not use an `array`, it's forbidden .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int number;
    int *ptr;
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    ptr = &number;

    number = (int*)malloc(2000);

    do{
        printf("Enter a number : ");
        scanf("%d",ptr);

        printf("\n######\n");
        printf("%d. number = %d \t%p\n",i+1,*(ptr),(ptr+i));
        printf("\n######\n");
        i++;
    } while(((number)) != 0);

    printf("\n!!!!############!!!!\n");
    for(j = 0 ; j < i; j++){
        number=number+j;
        printf("%d. number = %d \t%p\n",j+1,(number),&(number));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are a few things wrong with your code. I think you should read up on pointers, `scanf` and `malloc` to make sure you know how to use them.

Comment: thank you for help.
'&(number)' this line give the adress but interesting i cant take the numbers from address. can you help me for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code has a number of problems. I think you tried something too challenging for your level of understanding right now.

You should learn about pointers from the beginning and make sure you understand the `*` and `&` operators. Try writing some small simple programs so you have a good grasp on them.

From there you can move on to `scanf` and `malloc`, since they rely on heavily pointers.

Here is a working version of your code:

```
int main()
{
    int* number;      // this is should be a pointer
    //int *ptr;
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    //ptr = &number;

    number = (int*)malloc(2000);

    do{
        printf("Enter a number : ");

        // scan an integer into the ith place in memory
        //     after the address pointed to by "number"
        scanf("%d",number+i);   //number+i is already an address, don't use &

        printf("\n######\n");
        printf("%d. number = %d \t%p\n",i+1,*(number+i),number+i);
        printf("\n######\n");
        i++;
        // need to use a -1 since we incremented i
    }while(*(number+i-1) != 0);

    printf("\n!!!!############!!!!\n");
    for(j = 0 ; j < i; j++){
        //=number+j;
        printf("%d. number = %d \t%p\n",j+1,*(number+j),number+j);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @abbays. I think everyone finds pointers confusing when they first learn them. I found [this series of videos on pointers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2_aWCzGMAwLZp6LMUKI3cc7pgGsasm2_) very helpful if you are interested.